# Pass parameters to actionresult from jsonresult

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I wrote code to filter results like following image ,

[image]

once after it filter I want to send model values of following field as parameters to another controller method, I can call that method once I click **Generate Report** button

this is view file

```
@model project_name.Models.SearchVM
....
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    ....
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Type, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Type, Model.TypeList, "Select the type", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...............
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="button" value="Generate Report" class="btn btn-success submit" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ReportExport", "Home", new { type = Model.Type , ............. })'" /> &nbsp; <button id="search" type="button" class="btn btn-success submit">Search</button>
            </div>                      
        </div>
    </div>
}
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Product name</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            .........
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="table"></tbody>
</table>

<table id="template" class="table" style="display: none;">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        ........
        <td><a>Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>   

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd', changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true, yearRange: '1910:2015'
            });
        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var url = '@Url.Action("FetchProducts")';
        var editUrl = '@Url.Action("Edit")';
        var type = $('#Type');
        ..............

        var template = $('#template');
        var table = $('#table');
        $('#search').click(function () {
            table.empty();
            $.getJSON(url, { type: type.val(), ......, function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    var clone = template.clone();
                    var cells = clone.find('td');
                    cells.eq(0).text(item.ID);
                    cells.eq(1).text(item.Name);
                    cells.eq(2).text(item.Type);
                    ........................
                    cells.eq(7).text(item.Status);
                    var href = '@Url.Action("Edit")' + '/' + item.ID;
                    cells.eq(8).children('a').attr('href', href);
                    table.append(clone.find('tr'));
                });
            });
        });
    </script>


}
```

I want to call and send parameters to **ReportExport** method once I click **Generate Report** button

But I'm getting null values , I think this is because of I'm doing searching using Json , So How can I get **Type** value and send that as parameter ,

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ReportExport(string id, string type, ...........)
{
```

Comment: Razor code is parsed on the server before its sent to the view so `@Url.Action("ReportExport", "Home", new { type = Model.Type, ...` is passing the initial values of your model to the `ReportExport)()` method, not the values you edited in the view. You can use jQuery to build the url based on your edited values

Comment: @StephenMuecke appricate if you can refer example for "use jQuery to build the url based on edited values"

Comment: I tried to bind values inside JsonResult `ViewBag.type=type` then view `onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ReportExport", "Home", new { type = @ViewBag.type ,` but seems same result

Comment: using `ViewBag` is the same issue - it uses the initial value of the `ViewBag` property when you first render the view. It does not take account of the edited values in you view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'Generate Report' button includes `@Url.Action("ReportExport", "Home", new { type = Model.Type, ...` which is razor code. Razor code is parsed on the server before its sent to the view so its generating the route values based on the initial values of your model, not the edited values.

You can use jQuery to build you url based on the form controls.

Html

```
<input type="button" id="report" data-baseurl="@Url.Action("ReportExport", "Home")" value="Generate Report" class="..." />
```

Script

```
$('#report').click(function() {
  // build the url
  var url = $(this).data('baseurl') + '?type=' + $('#Type').val() + '&category=' + $('#Category').val() + ......;
  // redirect
  location.href = url;
});
```

Comment: once I set up this getting this error `The resource cannot be found.` and url is like `http://localhost:49669/Home/undefined?type=004&category=&country=&subsidary=`

Comment: Something weird there :) - `@Url.Action("ReportExport", "Home")` generates `../Home/ReportExport`, not `../Home/undefined` - inspect the html your generating to see what the `data-baseUrl` value is

Comment: Also there may be a conflict with the `var url = ...` you have in the other script. Suggest you give it a unique name (say) `var reportUrl = .....; location.href = reportUrl;`

Comment: Is there any other issue with `[HttpGet]` upon controller method ?

Comment: No. The issue is the url your generating - it should not have `/undefined` in it

Comment: I cannot understand how its taking undefined as its controller

Comment: Just try it as `var baseUrl = @Url.Action("ReportExport", "Home");` and check the output. It should be `/Home/ReportExport` (I'm not sure what you doing at the moment to generate `/Home/undefined`

Comment: this is controller look like `public ActionResult ReportExport(string id, string type, string category, string country, string subsidary, string dateHERE)
        {`

So I change my paramerters like this -------------------------------------------------------------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>> `var reportUrl = $(this).data('baseUrl') + '?id=' + "PDF" + '&type=' + $('#Type').val() + '&category=' + $('#Category').val() + '&country=' + $('#Country').val() + '&subsidary=' + $('#Subsidary').val() + '&dateHERE=' + $('#Date').val();`

Comment: That should all work fine but is irrelevant. The issue is the url. You need to ensure the value of `baseUrl` is correct (which needs to be `/Home/ReportExport`). And `string dateHERE` should be `DateTime dateHERE` assuming is actually is a date.

Answer (score 2):

`@Url.Action()` 
is razor code. It's evaluated on the server before it's sent to the view. So you have to build your URL like quoted above.

```
 var url = $(this).data('baseurl') + '?type=' + $('#Type').val() + '&category=' + $('#Category').val() + ...;
```